# iPhone Single Picker

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am trying to create a picker like the one in the picture below.  The picker I create usually have a smaller border.

How do you create a picker like the picture below.

[image: iPhone Picker]

Comment: What frame are you creating it with?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by frame here?

Comment: What code do you use to create your picker view?

Comment: Do you want to know how to create a picker with a single component? If yes, then you need to return 1 from - `(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView`

Comment: When I create a picker with one component, the picker is not so wide.

Comment: try with this - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component{
 return 150;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the

```
pickerView:widthForComponent
```

method of the UIpickerViewDelegate Protocol.

like this:

```
- (CGFloat) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
//if you have just one component, simply return a value you want
return 120.0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can not believe I did not see that in Apple's documentation